# AngularJS moving items between two select list

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to move items between two select lists using the code below, but items are not moved from the availableClients list to selectedClients lists, so can someone please check the code below and let me know what I am missing here? Thanks

```
  <div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl">

            <label for="aclients">Available Clients</label>                                
            <select size="5" multiple ng-model="available" ng-options="client.id as client.Name for client in clientsList" style="width: 400px"></select>         

            <input id="moveright" type="button" value="Add Client" ng-click="moveItem(available[0], availableclients,selectedclients)" />
            <input id="moverightall" type="button" value="Add All Clients" ng-click="moveAll(availableclients,selectedclients)" />
            <input id="move left" type="button" value="Remove Client" ng-click="moveItem(selected[0], selectedclients,availableclients)" />    
            <input id="moveleftall" type="button" value="Remove All Clients" ng-click="moveAll(availableclients,selectedclients)" />

            <label for="sclients">Selected Clients</label>                                                    
            <select size="5" multiple ng-model="selected" ng-options="client.id as client.Name for client in selectedclients" style="width: 400px"></select>
            <div>Selected Clients IDs: {{selectedclients}}</div>           

  </div>
  </div>
```

Controller:

```
  app.controller('testCtrl',
        function testCtrl($scope, clientsService){


   $scope.clientsList = clientsService.getClientsList().then(
            function(response){
               $scope.clientsList = response;
            },
            function(status){
               console.log(status);
            }
    );              

    $scope.moveItem = function(item, from, to) {

        console.log('Move item   Item: '+item+' From:: '+from+' To:: '+to);
        //Here from is returned as blank and to as undefined

        var idx=from.indexOf(item);
        if (idx != -1) {
            from.splice(idx, 1);
            to.push(item);      
        }
    };
    $scope.moveAll = function(from, to) {

        console.log('Move all  From:: '+from+' To:: '+to);
        //Here from is returned as blank and to as undefined

        angular.forEach(from, function(item) {
            to.push(item);
        });
        from.length = 0;
    };                

    $scope.availableclients = [];                
    $scope.selectedclients = [];                                


  });
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are several small problems in your template:

- You're moving objects from `availableclients` to `selectedclients`, but the first select displays options from `clientsList`, and not from `availableclients`
- You're moving IDs rather than objects. Your ng-options should simply be

  ```
  client as client.name for client in availableclients
  ```
- Your *remove all* button moves from available to selected, instead of moving from selected to available.

Here is a working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/RYEmpkBjQStoCfgpWPEK?p=preview

```
<label for="aclients">Available Clients</label>                                
<select size="5" multiple ng-model="available" ng-options="client as client.name for client in availableclients" style="width: 400px"></select>         

<input id="moveright" type="button" value="Add Client" ng-click="moveItem(available[0], availableclients,selectedclients)" />
<input id="moverightall" type="button" value="Add All Clients" ng-click="moveAll(availableclients,selectedclients)" />
<input id="move left" type="button" value="Remove Client" ng-click="moveItem(selected[0], selectedclients,availableclients)" />    
<input id="moveleftall" type="button" value="Remove All Clients" ng-click="moveAll(selectedclients,availableclients)" />

<label for="sclients">Selected Clients</label>                                                    
<select size="5" multiple ng-model="selected" ng-options="client as client.name for client in selectedclients" style="width: 400px"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, the sample you provided works great but only when I first pass the result set returned from $scope.clientsList to $scope.availableclients. If I try to load from $scope.clientsList as I was initially doing in my question it won't load any data in the Available Clients list.....so am I missing something / doing something wrong here? Thanks in advance

Comment: That's one of the problems: use availableclients consistently, or clientsList consistently, but not both.

Comment: That is very good. But I have a further issue. When I move this logic to a directive (so I can re-use it) I have the following happen:
* Select item from availableClients list that is NOT the bottom item
* Click Add Client (it Works)
* Try to select another item from avaliableClients
The List box is "Locked??!". 
It has the focus, but no items can be selected.
NOTE: if I choose the bottom item and move that, I can select another
So has anybody got a clue about this?

Comment: @GregJF Ask your own question withe the code, a plunkr,, etc.

Comment: Awesome @JBNizet. Works perfectly! However, how would you handle moving multiple selected items at once, since the select allows for multiple selections?

Comment: @sfinks_29 Instead of available[0] and selected[0], use available and selected, and move all elements of available or selected to the destination array.

Comment: @JBNizet what if we need to high-let the moved item, example: if i have added client as foo, then the client should be added and get highlighted as selected.

Answer (score 0):

In regard to my comment/question. I actually found an answer.
So for those that come here and have the same issue, here is what I found.

When moving a item from one SELECT list to another SELECT list, the angular model on the source list can get "lost".
To avoid this, the changed to each list must be done in separate  $apply function call. Here is a cut down example from within in the event handler

```
onClickRight = function (item, from, to) {
    var self = this;
    var selecteditem = angular.copy(item);
    self.$timeout(function () {
        self.scope.$apply(function () {                
            for (var idx = 0; idx < from.length; idx++) {
                if (from[idx].value == item.value && from[idx].displayValue == item.displayValue) {
                   item.length = 0;
                   from.splice(idx, 1);
                   break;
                 }          
                };
            });
        }, 200);
        self.$timeout(function () {
            self.scope.$apply(function () {
                to.push(selecteditem); 
            });
        }, 300);
    };
```

The 'item' is cloned with angular.copy so it can be used in the second angular $apply 
My options have a 2 properties: value and displayValue
I also assign $timeout and $scope to the 'self' variable in the directive's constructor.
Hope this helps