# Highlight moved item from one listbox to other listbox in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

There are two listbox, We need move to list items between the box.
Moving the item from one to other isn't the question.
This is already posted in the question
[AngularJS moving items between two select list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558091/angularjs-moving-items-between-two-select-list)
Here is the plunker link http://plnkr.co/edit/RYEmpkBjQStoCfgpWPEK?p=preview for moving one list item in other

The question/problem is how to highlight the moved item from one list item to other list item

```
<label for="aclients">Available Clients</label>                                
<select size="5" multiple ng-model="available" ng-options="client as client.name for client in availableclients" style="width: 400px"></select>         

<input id="moveright" type="button" value="Add Client" ng-click="moveItem(available[0], availableclients,selectedclients)" />
<input id="moverightall" type="button" value="Add All Clients" ng-click="moveAll(availableclients,selectedclients)" />
<input id="move left" type="button" value="Remove Client" ng-click="moveItem(selected[0], selectedclients,availableclients)" />    
<input id="moveleftall" type="button" value="Remove All Clients" ng-click="moveAll(selectedclients,availableclients)" />

<label for="sclients">Selected Clients</label>
```

Script

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('MoveCtrl', function($scope) {


$scope.moveItem = function(item, from, to) {

    console.log('Move item   Item: '+item+' From:: '+from+' To:: '+to);
    //Here from is returned as blank and to as undefined

    var idx=from.indexOf(item);
    if (idx != -1) {
        from.splice(idx, 1);
        to.push(item);      
    }
};
$scope.moveAll = function(from, to) {

    console.log('Move all  From:: '+from+' To:: '+to);
    //Here from is returned as blank and to as undefined

    angular.forEach(from, function(item) {
        to.push(item);
    });
    from.length = 0;
};                

$scope.selectedclients = [];                                

$scope.availableclients = [
  {
    id: 1, 
    name: 'foo'
  }, 
  {
    id: 2, 
    name: 'bar'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'baz'
  }
];
```

});

Early replies are appreciated.

Comment: script.js in your plunker is blank !!!

Comment: @AkberIqbal No its not. Please check again

Comment: What you mean by highlight? you want to show effect or what?

Comment: @Justcode, Yes I want to show the effect as it is selected after getting moved.

Comment: You need to use some plugin http://kamilkp.github.io/angular-sortable-view/#?tab=1